# R: Producing frequency table by selecting certain rows

Tags: r

I have a minimal example of a  data set D that looks something like:

```
 score person freq
    10      1    3
    10      2    5
    10      3    4
     8      1    3
     7      2    2
     6      4    1
```

Now, I want to be able to plot frequency of score=10 against person.

However, if I do:

```
#My bad, turns out the next line only works for matrices anyway:
#D = D[which(D[,1] == 10)]

D = subset(D, score == 10)
```

then I get:

```
score person freq
   10      1    3
   10      2    5
   10      3    4
```

However, this is what I *would* like to get:

```
score person freq
   10      1    3
   10      2    5
   10      3    4
   10      4    0
```

Is there any quick and painless way for me to do this in R?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a base R approach:

```
subset(as.data.frame(xtabs(freq ~ score + person, df)), score == 10)
#   score person Freq
#4     10      1    3
#8     10      2    5
#12    10      3    4
#16    10      4    0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `complete()` from the `tidyr` package to create the missing rows and then you can simply subset:

```
library(tidyr)
D2 <- complete(D, score, person, fill = list(freq = 0))
D2[D2$score == 10, ]
## Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
## 
##   score person  freq
##   (int)  (int) (dbl)
## 1    10      1     3
## 2    10      2     5
## 3    10      3     4
## 4    10      4     0
```

`complete()` takes as the first argument the data frame that it should work with. Then follow the names of the columns that should be completed. The argument `fill` is a list that gives for each of the remaining columns (which is only `freq` here) the value they should be filled with.

As suggested by [docendo-discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus), this can be further simplified by using also the `dplyr` package as follows:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
complete(D, score, person, fill = list(freq = 0)) %>% filter(score == 10)
```

Comment: Or with dplyr-piping `complete(df, score, person, fill = list(freq = 0)) %>% filter(score == 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` approach:

```
D %>%   mutate(freq = ifelse(score == 10, freq, 0),
               score = 10) %>%
        group_by(score, person) %>%
        summarise(freq = max(freq))

Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: score [?]

  score person  freq
  (dbl)  (int) (dbl)
1    10      1     3
2    10      2     5
3    10      3     4
4    10      4     0
```